# Fail2ban Regex help for banning sshd connection attempts

Tags: ubuntu, regular-expression, sshd, fail2ban

This is a tricky questions (for me)

I'm trying to setup fail2ban to BAN all connection attempts to my ssh server that don't login.

Now, my issue is.. everything, in the file filter.d/sshd.conf.

for me it's **incomprehensible**, *jibbrish*, I simply can't understand the regex (*I can't understand regex at all, and believe me, I've tried*) in that configuration file.

I want to scan and ban on this line of the log: (since it shows a connection that only connected)

**Connection closed by 192.168.0.2 port 12210 [preauth]**

now, as I wrote earlier, I have **NO** idea how or where to write/put it in the configuration file (*didn't want to clog the forum with an standard file*) [This one](https://dropbox.gr1.se/sshd.conf)

so if someone would be so kind of help me what I should write, and where I should put it in the configuration file.

And, if possible, explain (or at least try to) what you're doing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For latest versions of fail2ban it would be enough to set:

```
[sshd]
mode = aggressive
enabled = true
```

in your `/etc/fail2ban/jail.local`.

For some older version it depends.
Anyway I'd start with updating of filter config (e. g. from [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/fail2ban/fail2ban/0.11/config/filter.d/sshd.conf)), just ensure to replace `F-MLFGAINED` with `F-NOFAIL` if your version is older than 0.10.5 (introduced in https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban/commit/1c1d2cc435d6e8f1eb4a1b60c935a1385a82e295).

If your fail2ban is older than 0.10 (so 0.9), better would be to upgrade it.

Back to the actual question "how to extend stock regex's"... It would be possible with this setting:

```
[sshd]
failregex = %(known/failregex)s
            ^Connection closed by <ADDR> port \d+ \[preauth\]
```

(for the fail2ban <= 0.9 without `prefregex`, you have to specify whole RE with prefix-line etc and use `<HOST>` instead of `<ADDR>`).

Comment: I'm using 0.11. but where in the sshd.conf file should I put it? there isn't any [sshd] in there.  F-MLGAINED/F-NOFAIL what's that?

Comment: You've to create empty file `/etc/fail2ban/jail.local` and put it there (every setting there overwrites corresponding entry in section with same name of default `jail.conf`). As for F-MLGAINED/F-NOFAIL, you don't need to change it - the config I suggested must be compatible to 0.11.

Comment: aha, I thought I needed to add the regex to /etc/fail2ban/filter.d/sshd.conf, will test it..

Answer (score 1):

I don't have much experience with this, but have you tried adding this line to `failregex`?

```
^Connection closed by 192.168.0.2 port 12210\s*%(__suff)s$
```

For any Host/port:

```
^Connection closed by <HOST>%(__on_port_opt)s\s*%(__suff)s$
```

Comment: but that would only block that IP and that port?

Comment: Yes, I edited my answer to adapt to any host/port. Also, it rather belongs to `failregex` (which contains `cmnfailre` anyway)